# Detect Keyboard event in Android 4.0+ WebView using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, keyboard

I'd like to detect keyboard click event (soft keyboard or physical keyboard)

I have a simple html and JS that runs fine in various browser in Mac/Windows, even in Android's Chrome browser (both soft and physical keyboard can be detected).  I understand that WebView may not be based on Chrome (until 4.4)

```
document.onkeyup = function(event){
    alert("found keyup with value: " + event.which); 
};
```

In an Android app, I have a WebView that open the same webpage,

Somehow the above code can't detect any key press.  I have tried using different ways to get the key event, such as JQuery:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    alert("keyup with value: " + event.which); 
 });
```

Is keyboard event disabled in WebView in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to request focus...

```
    _webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_super_webview);
    _webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

and not all keyboard press can be detected, for example, the Android 'menu' button